# How to test an ajax submition in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Specifically, how can I pass the static method Request.IsAjaxRequest()?

I get the exception 'System.ArgumentNullException' when I try to test the following code:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
  return Json(data);
}
return View(data2);
```

I'm using Moq. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need mocking Request and Request.Headers to work with Request.IsAjaxRequest():

```
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
request.SetupGet(x => x.Headers).Returns(new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection {
    {"X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"}
});

var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);

var controller = new YourController();
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
```