# Unit Testing Controller Actions that call IsAjaxRequest()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, unit-testing, moq

Some of my controller actions need to respond with different ViewResults depending whether or not they were called by an AJAX request. Currently, I'm using the `IsAjaxRequest()` method to check for this. When this method is called during a unit test, it throws an `ArgumentNullException` because the HTTP context is missing.

Is there a way to mock/fake this call? Or is this a sign I should be checking for an AJAX request another way?

Comment: SO-How to test an ajax submition in ASP.NET MVC? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010900/how-to-test-an-ajax-submition-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Would it help if you provide a Test Double for the HTTP Context?

This can be done like this:

```
var httpCtxStub = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

var controllerCtx = new ControllerContext();
controllerCtx.HttpContext = httpCtxStub.Object;

sut.ControllerContext = controllerCtx;
```

where `sut` represents the System Under Test (SUT), i.e. the Controller you wish to test.

This example uses Moq.

Answer (score 5):

Using `moq` library in MVC test projects

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index()
    {
        // Arrange
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        controller.injectContext();
        // controller.injectContext(ajaxRequest: true);

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
}


public static class MvcTestExtensions
{
    public static void injectContext(this ControllerBase controller, bool ajaxRequest = false)
    {
        var fakeContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        fakeContext.Setup(r => r.HttpContext.Request["X-Requested-With"])
            .Returns(ajaxRequest ? "XMLHttpRequest" : "");
        controller.ControllerContext = fakeContext.Object;
    }
}
```